# Bulk insert using ActiveJob and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulkinsert, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I would like to create a bulk insert of jobs, just like that: `Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk('class' => MyWorker, 'args' => [...])` but using ActiveJob, I found nothing about that :/
Can someone share an example how can I do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that with Active Job.  AJ does not wrap every single Sidekiq feature.

Comment: :/ thanks, it isn't about every single Sidekiq feature :) bulk insert is an important feature and others can do that too. anyway I really like Sidekiq, and now I think I'll go back to use the pure Sidekiq without AJ ^^

Answer (score 0):

it will be coming to rails 7.1 apparently https://rubyonrails.org/2023/2/24/this-week-in-rails-the-rails-foundation-update-perform_all_later-in-aj-and-more